# Wordpress on Nginx does not serve .css or .js or images

Tags: wordpress, windows, nginx

i am trying to set up Nginx so that i can run wordpress from it.
So far i have two pc both win 10. 
First one ( lets call it RED) has the latest Nginx install on it with php 7.x (zip) and mysql ( latest install, because zip is so broken for windows) and phpMyAdmin (zip).

Everything works on localhost, when accessed from localhost (mysql, php, css are loaded and js works with wordpress) and there were no problem installing wordpress.

RED has a latest Wordpress install with plugins that are tested working on apache 2.4

I have set up RED to have static 192.168.0.52 and it never changes so that i can access it from my other laptop ( lets call it BLACK).

Black laptop has set up to have LAN card a static IP as well as follows 192.168.0.50

Once i type http://192.168.0.52/ in chrome i can see the  php rendered wordpress site, only problem is that there is no styles, there is no js and no images.

After inspecting the page i see that all the .css, .js and images have 404 not found. That is because the url to image points to my localhost (on BLACK laptop) looks like this

```
http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat/js/jquery.c00kie.js?ver=4.13
```

The links on the dynamicaly generated menu point to localhost as well. such as

```
http://localhost/myaccount/
```

If i replace localhost with the IP of the RED pc then i can access the content like this

```
 http://192.168.0.52/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat/js/jquery.c00kie.js?ver=4.13
```

I have included Access Logs, Error Logs and Nginx config below, but i did not see anything wrong(perhaps because i don't know what to look for). Searching on internet also did not yield me any results ( but i found a lot of other things such as caching and rewrite rules and permissions and other stuff)

**Whats wrong with Nginx and why is it not serving proper links?**

This should not be some kind of network related issue right?
Red is connected with Wi-Fi and Black is connected with rj45 patch cable to a  Dlink DWR-921 because the LAN port on the RED is not working properly.

Access logs paste bin https://pastebin.com/mWVGhRgs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2017:14:19:31 +0200] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1498479570.4888958930969238281250 HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "WordPress/4.8; http://localhost"
192.168.0.50 - - [26/Jun/2017:14:19:31 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 26934 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Error logs pastebin https://pastebin.com/4GFjyRjY

Nginx config pastebin https://pastebin.com/DARtqUgs

```
worker_processes  4;
error_log  logs/error.log  debug;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 150M;

    server{
          listen  *:80 default_server;
          server_name  localhost;
          root C:/nginx/public_html/localhost/;

          location / {
            index  index.php index.html;
          }
           location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
           }  
    }

    server{

          listen 127.0.0.1:8088;
          server_name  www.karamba.dev;
          root C:/nginx/public_html/karamba.dev/;

          location / {
            index  index.php index.html;
          }
           location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
           }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you [set the HOME and SITEURL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) in WordPress? I suspect it says `localhost`

Comment: hello, yes indeed it was still Localhost there. I changed it to the IP of the machine and now it is working for outside viewers, but now it is not working for localhost. I will check on the other issue tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, That indeed was the the problem, and i have solved it thanks to your help. It is strange how i never noticed this when i was setting up wordpress with Apache... If you format your comment as an answer i will gladly mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. In my case, the site was requesting the CSS and js files from the path with '/wordPress' appended to it. I followed the link by and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the insight.